# Dredd Tests with MariaDB using TravisCI

Tags: mariadb, travis-ci, dredd

Im trying to have travis run dredd tests during its build process. I realized that I will need to run mariaDB as part of the process. I am unsure how to create a table or insert sample data prior to dredd tests being run. I have added mariadb as an addon to the travis.yml and thats about it.
Also to make dredd run in travis I will be using docker-compose as well.

EDIT:

I have my travis.yml running

```
docker-compose up -d
sleep 30
BUNCH OF SQL COMMANDS to create tables and insert data
dredd
```

But at this point my dredd.yml has

```
server: docker-compose up
```

so i seem to call docker-compose first in travis and run mysql commands and then call it again right before dredd. I believe I should only need to do it right before the dredd tests in a hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

In my travis.yml I:

```
docker-compose up -d
sleep 30
~~RUN SQL COMMANDS TO CREATE TABLES/ADD DATA~~
docker-compose stop
sleep 5 (to allow for compose to start up)
dredd
```

Then in my dredd.yml:

```
server: docker-compose up
server-wait: 60
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend Dredd tests with "setup" and "teardown" actions, which would fill the database before your API gets tested, and clear the database afterwards (to isolate individual tests).

You can use [Dredd Hooks](https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hooks/) to do that. The concept of [Isolation of HTTP Transactions](https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/#isolation-of-http-transactions) is also described in the Dredd docs.

Comment: How would i get the db in the hook javascript file? var db = require("./src/db"); hooks.beforeAll(...?

Comment: I did, the module 'db' was not recognized.
I opted to put 
-docker-compose up -d, sleep 30, sql commands
in a script that i call in the dredd.yml file as server: ./script.sh Doing that seems to insert the data correctly but then the dredd tests error out "fail: Error connecting to server under test!"

Comment: I'm sorry, that's quite specific problem to solve in comments here. Feel free to file an issue on Dredd repo or to write to support@apiary.io, where we can discuss this in detail.